# Eclipse Editor Plugin - refresh syntax coloring

Tags: eclipse, syntax, colors

i got problem with syntax coloring. Everything works fine when i type by keyboard, but when i paste text or when i add something by code(i.e. AutoIndention adds some text), no coloring are applied. I am extending TextEditor. Can't figure why there is no refresh syntax method in sourceViewer. Any help would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ITextViewer.invalidateTextPresentation()` to tell the viewer that the text presentation needs to be redone (`ISourceViewer` extends `ITextViewer` so this is available in a source viewer).

Comment: Thanks, thats helps me a lot ! I've added document listener, set up for events with text longer than 1, and then i am firing ITextViewer.invalidateTextPresentation() .